# List of DirectShow filters with details

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I have a list of DirectShow filters in C# using [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). I get a list of filters by `IFilterMapper2.EnumMatchingFilters()`. But I've got just `FriendlyName` and `FilterData`:

```
hr = propertyBag.Read("FriendlyName", out friendlyName, null);
hr = propertyBag.Read("FilterData", out filterDataObj, null);
```

I would like to have get "File Name", and "File Version", which shows [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) and other tools. How can I retrieve these informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked into the GraphStudioNext sources and found that I have to get CLSID and get dll file name from registry:

```
hr = propertyBag.Read("CLSID", out clsid, null);
string dllFile = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID\\" + clsid + "\\InProcServer32").GetValue("") as string;
```

Finally, the File version can be retrieved by:

```
string fileVersion = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(dllFile).FileVersion;
```